# Local Notifications not displaying in iOS 6

Tags: ios, notifications, ios6, nsnotificationcenter

I am getting local notifications on time but they are just creating sound. I have disabled the "Do Not Disturb" option and set the Notification alert style as "Alert".

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Is it working in iOS 5 ? I think this could help someone answer your question.

Comment: Yes, It is.Now is only creating sound. I need Alerts.

Answer (score 3):

When the application is not active (in foreground), the OS will display an alert, play a sound and/or create a badge. When the application is active, there are no such thing happening. Instead, it'll call the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method on your app delegate, in which you will have to create your own alert, play your own sound, etc.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: It is really unusual. I have set the notification alert style as "Alert" but it is still showing as "Banner". It is working fine after restarting the iPhone 4s.